# How can I solve this flutter problem? Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'

Tags: flutter, dart

**Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.**
[image: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SchedulerBinding.instance is not nullable. Fix that, you will fix your build.